# Como quitar los espacios de una frase de una cadena de carácteres c++

Tags: c++, caracteres, string

Quiero que el usuario introduzca por pantalla la cadena de carácteres con espacios pero luego quiero quitar esos espacios.

Quiero guardar en el char `Cadenajunt` la frase sin los espacios.

```
char Cadena[120];
char Cadenajunt[120];
    int i, v, ii, r; 
    gets(Cadena);
```

Comment: Como sugerencia, procura incluir en tu prgunta lo que tú has intentado hacer para resolver el problema y el por qué estos intentos han fallado.

Answer (score 4):

Mi consejo es que no uses `char[]` para manejar cadenas de caracteres en C++. Para trabajar con cadenas es preferible usar `std::string`:

STL al rescate ([ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0jhk5sekeksReYjl)):

```
std::string linea = "esto es una prueba";
std::remove_if(linea.begin(), linea.end(), ::isspace);
```

Otra posibilidad ([ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iOQPNTjjSVWeJxSh)):

```
std::string linea = "esto es una prueba";
linea.erase(std::remove(linea.begin(), linea.end(), ' '), linea.end());
```

También podemos usar `std::stringstream` ([ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7lu0MxcM6dnSLVnc)):

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "esto es una prueba";

std::string resultado;
std::string temp;
while( ss >> temp )
    resultado += temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando las mismas variables que defines, puedes usar la utilidad [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) de la cabecera `<algorithm>`:

```
char Cadena[120]{};
char Cadenajunt[120]{};
gets(Cadena);

std::copy_if(Cadena, Cadena + 120, Cadenajunt, [](auto c) { return !std::isspace(c); });
```

He añadido llaves vacías al final de las formaciones de caracteres para hacer que todo su contenido se inicialice a cero. Pero la manera adecuada de hacer esto en C++ es usando cadenas de caracteres `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string Cadena;
    std::string Cadenajunt;

    std::getline(std::cin, Cadena);
    std::copy_if(Cadena.begin(), Cadena.end(), std::back_inserter(Cadenajunt), [](auto c) { return !std::isspace(c); });

    std::cout << Cadenajunt;

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBTsMwDIbP5CmMuKQSVJzXigviBk@A0OS6JvNonZImh2ras5e269iEOEX/5/@TrVDXPTiicbwTpSbVDKX4PgbG9slcGFEcOr4mU0fUXRNsnA8Sd5NoRCO0KGozczA3faw3m5MAz1izYvEf3CeNhVknjmMjynYJJHq/lrKzSr4btvJpTziv2M3rzrWctZ7TUq2QvraiPYfIwV6WTfP3D4speqAMDhA4pqBwu0jS9x0SW8oKOGa/d5FPEcryz8mr@ViY4zi@KCSFJjkMMH3MK8IbKu1wDpQGD@rbKvD0wHcSDh6QfKgxtJznufkB)</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

Importa la librería  con `include <string.h>`

Crea un apuntador

```
char * apuntador;
```

Luego separalo con la función [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

```
apuntador = strtok (cadena," ");
```

Crear un ciclo para recorrer con tu apuntador mientras sea diferente de NULL usando la función [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)

```
while (apuntador != NULL)
  {
    strcat(cadenaJunt,apuntador);
    apuntador = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
```

Y tu cadena ya estaría almacenada en `cadenaJunt` sin espacios.

El código debería quedar así

```
    char cadena[120];
    char cadenaJunt[120] = "\0";
    gets(cadena);

    char * apuntador;
    apuntador = strtok (cadena," \0");
    while (apuntador != NULL) {
        strcat(cadenaJunt,apuntador);
        printf ("%s\n",apuntador);
        apuntador = strtok (NULL, " \0");
        }

    cout << cadenaJunt;
```

Comment: `<string.h>` es una cabecera de [tag:c] no de [tag:c++]. Esa cabecera **NO** debe ser usada en un programa de C++.

Answer (score -1):

Utiliza punteros:

```
char* pch=cadenaJunt;
for(char* ps1=Cadena;*ps1;ps1++){
      if(*ps1!=' ') {
          *pch=*ps1;
           pch++;
      }         
 }
*pch=0;
```

Comment: ¿Y no finalizas la cadena?

Comment: No, mejor que no use punteros. Mejor que use `std::string`.

Comment: eferion, tienes razón al final del for me faltó un *pch=0.

Comment: La opción punteros es válida considerando que el autor utiliza char[]. En todo caso la recomendación, si es a la que te refieres es que utilice std::string en todo en vez de char[]. Como lo propone eferion.

Comment: Usar punteros es propenso a errores, genera un código más complicado y está desaconsejado en C++ moderno. Es válido porque da el resultado correcto, pero es tan válido como decir que puedes recorrer toda Europa conduciendo marcha atrás: posiblemente llegarás a tu destino, pero nadie recomendaría hacerlo.

Comment: Así es,  pero mi propuesta es sobre la base que  el autor solo quiera utilizar c-strings y funciones de la stdio sin modificarle el código ya existente ni añadirle nuevas librerias. Ahora no creo que es como ir marcha atrás porque a las finales la  STL utiliza punteros dentro de sus funciones y no es que que la STL vaya hacia atras.  Sin embargo, lo mejor es utilizar la STL como lo que propone tú y eferion y porque nos evita programar con punteros..

Comment: Los c-strings no existen, son formaciones de caracteres con un nombre *bonito*, lo que el autor quiera es una conjetura porque no ha dicho que quiera o requiera usar formaciones de caracteres. La STL utiliza punteros pero los **oculta** mediante encapsulamiento, precisamente para evitar errores y hacer el código más sencillo, logro que se pierde sacando de nuevo fuera los punteros, eso es marcha atrás en el progreso.

Comment: Bueno, entonces los que desarrollan librerías como Boost, Poco  ellos si no van marcha atrás, solo los que queremos hacer nuestras propias librerías vamos marcha atrás? Ojo que yo estoy de acuerdo contigo en no utilizar punteros si puedes hacerlo  con  alternativas mejores. En lo que único que discrepo es que en ocasiones por circunstancias especiales son una buena alternativa. Con c-strings me refería a la cadena de caracteres terminados en nulo.